# Вывод самых популярных товаров

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как заменить этот код шорткода на аналогичный код, в котором используется WP_Query?

```
echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="12"]');
```

я делал так:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    $wc_query->the_post();

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

но дело в том, что магазин находится ещё в разработке, а самые популярные товары уже выводятся в результате этого кода. Ведь товары ещё не продавались.
Правильно ли я вывожу самые продаваемые товары?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код правильный. Он выводит записи типа `product` по 12 на страницу, сортируя их по мета-полю `total_sales`. Пока продаж нет, у всех товаров это поле равно 0.

Значение мета-поля `total_sales` можно вывести в цикле после `wc_get_template_parts`, например:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'total_sales')[0];
```

Чтобы вывести товары, у которых число продаж больше заданного (в примере > 0), можно использовать `meta_query`. Два варианта цикла ниже.

```
echo '<h2>Самые продаваемые циклом woocommerce</h2>';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        $wc_query->the_post();

        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            echo 'Кол-во продаж: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'total_sales')[0];
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();

echo '<h2>Самые продаваемые циклом woocommerce с ограничением</h2>';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => 'total_sales',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
    ),
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        $wc_query->the_post();

        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        echo 'Кол-во продаж: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'total_sales')[0];
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Результат теста [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so633301/).

Comment: > Поскольку продаж не было, у всех товаров в этом поле стоит 0. Сортировка пока не осуществляется.

Comment: тогда встречный вопрос: как тогда сделать, чтобы не выводились товары, пока они не будут популярны?

Comment: встречный вопрос к встречному вопросу)) - а что значит - популярны? критерий?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что best_selling_products означает самые продаваемые товары. Или лучше сильно не заморачиваться с популярными товарами как для нового магазина? Как сделать, чтобы пока нет самых продаваемых товаров, чтобы товары не выводились из этой таксономии? За ранее очень благодарен за подсказки.

Comment: best_selling - не таксономия. Это выборка по базе с сортировкой по мета-полю "количество продаж". Пока нет продаж, можно не выводить вообще

Comment: > Пока нет продаж, можно не выводить вообще

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть в запросе к бд?
Нужно использовать объект wpdb, в котором указать условие where для метаполя total_sales > 0?

Comment: Я исправил ответ. На самом деле, пока нет продаж, поле `total sales` отсутствует, и код не выводит ничего.

Comment: > На самом деле, пока нет продаж, поле total sales отсутствует, и код не выводит ничего.

Comment: При создании нового товара поле total_sales автоматически создаётся со значением 0

Comment: мда, так и есть - проверил по базе

Comment: > Значение мета-поля total_sales можно вывести в цикле после wc_get_template_parts

Comment: А для чего выводить значение этого метаполя, если товар уже выведен, даже который ещё не продавался?

Comment: Для отладки. Расширил ответ. Надеюсь, теперь все ясно.